# How can I portably turn on large file support?

Tags: c, portability, large-files, large-file-support

I am currently writing a C program that reads and writes files that might be over 2 GiB in size. On linux **feature_test_macros**(7) specifies:

> ```
>    _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
>           Expose definitions for the alternative API specified by the LFS (Large File Summit) as a  "tran‐
>           sitional  extension"  to  the  Single  UNIX  Specification.  (See ⟨http://opengroup.org/platform
>           /lfs.html⟩) The alternative API consists of a set of new objects  (i.e.,  functions  and  types)
>           whose names are suffixed with "64" (e.g., off64_t versus off_t, lseek64() versus lseek(), etc.).
>           New programs should not employ this interface; instead _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 should be employed.
>
>    _FILE_OFFSET_BITS
>           Defining this macro with the value 64 automatically converts references to 32-bit functions  and
>           data  types related to file I/O and file system operations into references to their 64-bit coun‐
>           terparts.  This is useful for performing I/O on large files (> 2 Gigabytes) on  32-bit  systems.
>           (Defining  this macro permits correctly written programs to use large files with only a recompi‐
>           lation being required.)  64-bit systems naturally permit file sizes greater  than  2  Gigabytes,
>           and on those systems this macro has no effect.
> ```

Is this guaranteed to be portable?

Solaris suggests in **lfcompile**(5):

> ```
>  Applications can be compiled in the large  file  compilation
>  environment by using the following methods:
>
>      o    Use the getconf(1) utility with one or more of  the
>           arguments listed in the table below. This method is
>           recommended for portable applications.
>
>           ____________________________________________________________
>          |     argument     |                 purpose                |
>          |__________________|________________________________________|
>          | LFS_CFLAGS       |  obtain compilation flags necessary  to|
>          |                  |  enable   the  large  file  compilation|
>          |                  |  environment                           |
>          | LFS_LDFLAGS      |  obtain link editor options            |
>          | LFS_LIBS         |  obtain link library names             |
>          | LFS_LINTFLAGS    |  obtain lint options                   |
>          |__________________|________________________________________|
>
>      o    Set the compile-time flag _FILE_OFFSET_BITS  to  64
>           before including any headers. Applications may com-
>           bine objects produced in the large file compilation
>           environment  with  objects  produced in the transi-
>           tional compilation environment, but must be careful
>           with  respect  to  interoperability  between  those
>           objects. Applications  should  not  declare  global
>           variables of types whose sizes change between  com-
>           pilation environments.
> ```

Is this portable? On my linux machine, passing these keys to **getconf** will output nothing. (Which means the keys exist).

Is there any portable approach?

Comment: Are there any machines left that can't handle 2 GB files?

Comment: @CarlNorum It's not about machines that can't handle them. Even on current i386 Linuxes, if you open() a file that is larger than 4 GiB without O_LARGEFILE, you get an EOVERFLOW.

Dealing with large files requires that you have a 64 bits datatype. Since some utilities relying on a 32 bit offsets into files, you have to turn on large file support during compilation before you can use large files.

Comment: Once, I demoed a simple XOR file encryption program I wrote. I thought why not encrypt that really big movie file I have. Short story, the demo didn't go that well. I would like to know what (if any) portable solutions exist.

Comment: @FUZxxl: If `getconf` is outputting nothing it probably means that you *don't* need any special flags for large file support - probably because your environment is 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`confstr` interface](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/confstr.html) or the corresponding [`getconf` program](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getconf.html) and try the various `_CS_POSIX_V7_ILP32_OFFBIG_CFLAGS`, etc. options until you find one that works. This will give you `CFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS`, and `LIBS` needed for an appropriate environment.

Comment: "Find one that works" does not really sound like a portable way. I don't have every existing Unix system at my disposal and guesswork won't give me certanity.

Comment: Did you actually read the links I provided that document these interfaces? That's actually how you use them. On any conforming system, if there is a compilation environment with the desired property that `off_t` is 64 bits, this will find it. If not, you're out of luck.

Comment: Yes I did. These documents define configuration keys for certain variable width values only. None of these keys mention large file support. Of course I could assume that the configuration key for large file support that exists on Solaris is portable, but this assumption is not backed up without a document describing that this behavior is portable.

Comment: I'm sorry for being such a dickhead. I have been enlighted.

Comment: Is there a way to do so on windows, and on posix it'd be great if I didn't have to specify the version of POSIX...